Decomposition of a contractive representation into an orthogonal sum for the $n$-dimensional case. Has this been done yet?
I know that it has been done for the two-dimensional case. Marek Kosiek showed it in his work "Decomposition of operator representations of the algebra $R(K_1 \times K_2)$" and "Functional Calculus and Common Invariant Subspaces".
The thing is that I'd highly need it for the $n$-dimensional case, as it would be very useful in a problem I am currently working on.
Now what does Kosiek work say about the two-dimensional case? If we have a product set $X := X_1 \times X_2$, where $X_j \in \mathbb{C}$ for $j\in \{1,2\}$, then the set of all complex Borel measures on $X$ (denoted by $M(X_1 \times X_2)$) can be decomposed into the direct sum of four mutually singular bands:
$$M(X_1 \times X_2) = M_0 \oplus M_1 \oplus M_2 \oplus M_3$$
where
$$M_0 \text{ is generated by the measures on }X_1 \times X_2 \text{ representing points in }Q_1 \times Q_2\text{, where }Q_j\text{ is the set of all non-peak points for function algebras } A_j \subset \mathbb{C}(X_j)$$
$$M_1 \text{ consists of the measures in }\langle R(X_1 \times X_2)^{\perp}\rangle = \{v \in M(X) \ | \ v \ll v_0 \in R(X_1 \times X_2)^{\perp}\} \text{ supported on sets of the form }E_1 \times X_2\text{, where }E_1\text{ is a nullset for }R(X_1)\text{. The sign "}\perp\text{" describes the annihilator.}$$
$$M_2 \text{ consists of the measures in }\langle R(X_1 \times X_2)^{\perp}\rangle \text{ supported on sets of the form }X_1 \times E_2\text{, where }E_2\text{ is a nullset for }R(X_2)$$
$$M_3 = \langle R(X_1 \times X_2)^{\perp}\rangle^s\text{, the "}^s\text{" means the singular measures}$$
Thanks to the decomposition of the elementary measures, we now can formulate the following theorem (Theorem 1.5 in Kosiek's "Functional Calculus and Common Invariant Subspaces"):

Any contractive representation $\Psi : R(X_1 \times X_2) \to L(H)$ decomposes into orthogonal sum $$\Psi = \Psi_0 \oplus \Psi_1 \oplus \Psi_2 \oplus \Psi_3$$ of representations $\Psi_j$ of $R(X_1 \times X_2)$ absolutely continuous with respect to the bands $M_j$ for $j=0,\ldots, 3$. This corresponds to the orthogonal decomposition $$H = H_0 + H_1 + H_2 + H_3, \quad H_j = \Psi_j(1)$$

My question is: Has this been proven and generalized for the $n$-dimensional case yet?

This was also asked on Math.SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4954947/decomposition-of-a-contractive-representation-into-an-orthogonal-sum-for-the-n
